# Best way to flatten an XML document

Tags: database, xml

Say you have a document like this:

```
<names>
  <first>Joe</first>
  <last>Smoe</last>
  <phonenumbers>
     <phonenumber type="home">123-567-9876</phonenumber>
     <phonenumber type="cell">345-678-1234</phonenumber>
  </phonenumbers>
  <emails>
     <email>abc@dfg.com</email>
     <email>xyz@lkj.com</email>
  </emails>
</names>
```

I am sort of stumped on the best table format when flattening this into table. In my case, it is a table for a Hive database.

I don't want 4 records for "Joe Smoe". So, can have fields like this "phone1", "phone2", "email1", "email2".

But this table actually is a Hive table so we do have "arrays" as a data types. So, I could have this:

```
last|first|phones                     |emails
----+-----+---------------------------+-------------------------
Joe |Smoe |[123-567-9876,345-678-1234]|[abc@dfg.com,xyz@lkj.com]
```

But then how to save the type of phone in the table. Maybe with a "map"?

```
last|first|phones                                     |emails
----+-----+-------------------------------------------+-------------
Joe |Smoe |[{"number":"123-567-9876", "type"="home"}] |
```

How would you flatten this type of XML (eg. collections in collections) into a flat table?

Comment: Hive is a "data warehouse" DBMs. Tables in such a system should be optimized for the queries you want to run, that is nothing you can determine from just looking at the XML structure of your input data.

Comment: Just to clarify, the table is not the final design for our project. We're just trying to get it into Hive just to even have the team look at it. There really are no other requirements other than to get the data into Hive. But I wanted to get as quick reasonable format.

Comment: then I recommend to use whatever works, and not to overanalyse. Looking for "the best" solution makes IMHO only sense when you have clarity about your criteria for "best".

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to map from XML to a relational model, you will have to have a one to many relationship from the name to the phone numbers. You will also need a one to many from the name to the email addresses.

**Entity Relationship Diagram** (ERD)

[image: Entity Relationship Diagram showing the one to many relationships between Names and PhoneNums and Names and Emails]

Names would need a primary key (designated PK on the image) to be used as a foreign key (designated FK on the image) in the related tables. According to my diagram, you would need a name to exist before you could create either the PhoneNum record or the Email record.  Also, the child records are optional.

Comment: I am writing generic code for more than just this XML doc so it hard to had it automatically create the relational model. I am more going for just single unnormalize table file format since it much easier to code. But I don't disagree with this approach.

Comment: Then why do you need to flatten the XML into a table?

Comment: Hive doesn't read XML files (or at least not efficiently). So, just need a file format that is acceptable.

Comment: @swdev: *"I am more going for just single unnormalize table file format since it much easier to code"* - sounds you are approaching this from the wrong direction. The first thing you should ask not is "what is easier to code" but "what are the requirements". And I guess your requirements are not just "store the data somehow in Hive", but "store them there for doing specific queries". Packing collections into single fields will *prevent* querying, so that is probably not what you want.